# Compilling eggdrop1.9.1 results in /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lieee

Tags: gcc

When trying to compile eggdrop1.9.1 gcc gives the following output

```
> gcc -g -O2 -pipe -Wall -I.. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -o ../eggdrop bg.o botcmd.o botmsg.o botnet.o chanprog.o cmds.o dcc.o dccutil.o dns.o flags.o language.o match.o main.o mem.o misc.o misc_file.o modules.o net.o rfc1459.o tcl.o tcldcc.o tclhash.o tclmisc.o tcluser.o tls.o userent.o userrec.o users.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6  -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lssl -lcrypto -ldl  -lresolv md5/md5c.o compat/*.o `cat mod/mod.xlibs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lieee
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'link' failed
make[2]: *** [link] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/eggdrop-1.9.1/src'
Makefile:54: recipe for target '../eggdrop' failed
make[1]: *** [../eggdrop] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/eggdrop-1.9.1/src'
Makefile:243: recipe for target 'eggdrop' failed
make: *** [eggdrop] Error 2
```

Can anyone suggest how I could resolve this please?

[EDIT for OS version & further info]
This is on Ubuntu 18.04.1, ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27 I am using ftp.eggheads.org/pub/eggdrop/source/1.9/eggdrop-1.9.1.tar.gz, complete output from the build process is at https://pastebin.com/5hdLVC5k

Comment: Install the -devel package for **libieee**, example Debian / Mint / Ubuntu : `libieee1284-3-dev` .... and Fedora / CentOS : `libieee1284-devel`

Comment: Thanks, I missed the "-3" part when I tried installing the devel package before, however the devel package installed correctly but gcc still returns the same error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lieee"

Comment: The only available package providing libieee.so / libieee.a on Debian is [libfreehdl0-dev](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libieee.a&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) and I'm really not sure that would be the right thing. eggdrop's comment in its configure file "# Also, Linux requires the "ieee" library for math to work right" looks strange.

Comment: Just made a quick check: on a Debian bullseye system -lieee is not used and default compilation succeeds. So OP should really provide additional information on the OS (BSD, Linux...) its version, its libc version if relevant etc. and what commands were used (right after de-archiving the .tgz) to get result using -lieee

Comment: Valid  `eggdrop-1.9.1.tar.gz` is  https://ftp.eggheads.org/pub/eggdrop/source/1.9/eggdrop-1.9.1.tar.gz . .... No issues. No asking for "libieee.so" !

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1, original post edited.

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27

I am using ftp.eggheads.org/pub/eggdrop/source/1.9/eggdrop-1.9.1.tar.gz 

The commands used were the usual "./configure", "make config" both of which completed with no errors, then "make" which fails.

Comment: Yet you still have to add the steps before getting the error. Even if not precisely the same OS, I can't reproduce, and an other person can't reproduce either. What would be probably useful is the relevant part(s) of the ./configure output.

Comment: I've just removed the eggdrop folder, redownloaded the source and tried to build it again. The complete output for the process is at https://pastebin.com/5hdLVC5k

Comment: works with a bionic LXC container (which is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS): no -lieee line appearing for TCL. tcl version differs, libc6 version differs etc. Maybe you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Also you're probably not telling everything: Ubuntu 18.04 provides kernel 4.15 not kernel 4.9 (which would be from Debian stretch). Fine if inside a container, might be not fine in some other cases.

Comment: It's a rented server, not in a container as far as I am aware, but I'll upgrade and see what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the server and still have the same error with lieee, I'm not in a position to wipe the server as it has 16tb of data I'd need to back up. While running eggdrop on it would be nice it's not important enough to wipe the box and start over so I'll just rent a smaller server for eggdrops.

Thanks for the information and all the attempts to help!

Comment: eggdrop, but not latest version, is provided by Ubuntu package. Why would you want to compile it in the first place? Do you need a new feature? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/eggdrop

Comment: the package worked except all dcc and telnet connections connected but immediately closed, even with no firewall running and on a known open port, so I figured to compile the latest version. I've rented an OVH VPS now and eggdrop is running fine on there so the issue is resolved.

Comment: it turns out the dcc/ctcp problem was my supposedly static IP had changed, but the eggdrop package has handlen of 9 and I need 32 so it won't work anyhow.